# Primefaces FileUpload avoid duplicate Files

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1.In fileUpload upload multiple files that time avoid for duplicate files to upload becuase I'm already upload tes.jpg again upload same it will be support so that time avoid to duplicate files.

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" 
mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="true" update="messages"  
fileLimit="6" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

Comment: I did not get the question. Avoid uploading duplicate files based on what? Image files cannot be distinguished based on their contents or using an algorithm. Therefore, it is solely the administrator's / user's responsibility to prevent files from being duplicated. If you are however, only concerned with file names being duplicated, then it is a different thing.

Comment: I need same file upload two times that time I need to show message

Comment: How would you in plain java check if two files with identical names (or not) are the same? Right, a checksum!

Comment: If there is any way check on duplicate file client because the user mistake browse to choose same file at two times that time need to show message